# Is Windows 7 still available for direct download?

Tags: windows-7, download

I remember being able to download Windows 7 directly from Digital River, but when I tried today, using the links provided [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-from-digital-river/), I found that the links aren't working. I don't know whether they stopped providing the downloads or whether this is just temporary. The one I'm after is X17-59337.iso (Professional N, English x64). Are there any other places where I can download this ISO, direct download or otherwise? (I'm assuming it's still legal.)

Comment: It works for me (on Linux) if I click on one of the mirrors (not the 1st) on the right hand side of the linked page. For example, [here](http://www.softpedia.com/dyn-postdownload.php?p=118183&t=0&i=2).

Comment: @terdon: Out of curiosity, what browser are you using? I'm using Chromium on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download is working for me just fine. Maybe you have some problem with your connection or browser. Try to use another browser or different connection.

Comment: Well, everything else is working fine. Since I can't think of anything, I'll trying booting to Windows (currently on Linux). I don't know why that would make a difference, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Can't think of anything that could cause it except of firewall or blocking of the server with ISO files by your provider.

Comment: Strange, after booting to Windows and trying the link, it works! Perhaps it is the browser. I was using Chromium.

Comment: I use Chromium as well on Ubuntu and it's working for me, can be some extension in browser. Try use other browser under Linux and if is working, it's browser, if not, than there is some problem with system, most probably firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's still legal to **download only** the installation of windows.
I really do not know why Microsoft decided to remove its download from their site, (probably to encourage the download of Windows 8).
But you can use [this site](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Windows-7-Download-118183.html) as a substitute.

Comment: The mirror just redirects to the digitalrivercontent link (the one that doesn't work for me). Is it working for you?

Comment: Actually Yes, it works great for me. /=
I cant see where it's redirects to the digitalrivercontent.
it looks like it's downloading Straight from softpedia.